# How to disable js and css caching in liferay?

Tags: liferay

I am developing a theme for liferay,but liferay caching system does not let me to see changes.
How can i disable liferay js and css caching?

PS: I am using Liferay version 5.1.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Under Tomcat (bundled)

Edit the `setenv.sh` file (`setenv.bat` on windows) 
Search for the line that sets the `JAVA_OPTS` variable 
Add `-Dexternal-properties=portal-developer.properties` to the list of options 
For example:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m  -XX:PermSize=32m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Duser.timezone=GMT+2 
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=$CATALINA_HOME/conf/jaas.config 
-Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false 
-Dexternal-properties=portal-developer.properties"
```

Note that this has to be all on one line.

If you were already using the external-properties system property to load some other properties file, add portal-developer.properties with commas.

This is however for the later version 5.2.3+
Not sure why you are still @ 5.1.1, I would update to take advantage of some updated structure and dev handling. In the past there was more work required to get the caching disabled.

Reference:
http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay%2BDeveloper%2BMode

Comment: Just to add more information to the @Jakub's reply. The file `portal-developer.properties` is already bundled in Liferay so don't worry to create one and/or to ask about what it should contains. In a standard Liferay installation (bundled with Tomcat) it should be located in: `./webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-developer.properties`.

Comment: @Rubens Mariuzzo, welcome, I know what a pain Liferay can be to work with ;)

Comment: Indeed, Liferay is pretty useful, but can make you spend hours in simple and common tasks for developers.

Comment: I'd like to suggest to change JAVA_OPTS to CATALINA_OPTS. Reference, justification and outcome: https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-26464

Comment: After making this change, is the restart of tomcat necessary?

Answer (score 6):

it's all about [Liferay servlet filters](http://marksweep.blogspot.com/2011/11/liferay-servlet-filtering.html). You need to turn some of them off. The best place for that is portal-developer-ext.properties.

You make liferay read it by 2 possible ways :

```
JVM parameter  -Dexternal-properties=portal-developer-ext.properties
```

or add this property to portal-ext.properties

```
include-and-override=portal-developer-ext.properties
```

Comment: Thanks for the bit about 'include-and-override'. I put that in my portal-ext.properties file on my Liferay 6.1.0 server and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

To disable caching of JS and CSS resources in Liferay Portal 6.1+*, add the following line to your **`portal-ext.propeties`** file:

```
browser.cache.disabled=true
```

<sup>*This may work in older versions as well, but I haven't tested it.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Below link have complete details how to manage caching in liferay

http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/10626805

Comment: As links tend to go off-line earlier or later, you could try to provide a summary of the things shown on that site.

Comment: Read the page, it's actually not about caching but about running a one-time-import. (Only in the title there is something written with caching of *.proerties files)